# При добавлении товара берёт только первую цифру из цикла

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть кусок кода, где в цикле `for` выводятся блоки, а также внутри ещё один цикл `for`, который выводит значения полей `option` и `value`. При добавлении товара берётся только первое значение, то есть выбираешь, например, 6, нажимаешь "добавить в корзину", а приходит цифра 1 всегда.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.name a').click(function(){
         $this = $(this);
         var id = $this.parent().find('select').attr('id');
  var count = $this.parent().find('option').val();
         alert(count);
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'post.php',
  data: {itemid: id, count: count},
  success: function(data){
  $this.parent().find('.add').html('Товар добавлен!');
     }
   });
});
});
```

```html
<?for($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++){?>
 <div id="wripper">
  <div class="name"> Товар №-<?=$i?>
   <img src="images/img.png" alt="">
                        <select id="item<?=$i?>">
                            <?for($q = 1; $q <= 9; $q++){?>
                           <option value="<?=$q?>"><?=$q?></option>
                           <?}?>
                        </select>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);">Добавить товар</a>
   <div class="add"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
<?}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <?for($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++){?>
        <div id="wripper">
            <div class="name"> Товар №-
                <?=$i?>
                    <img src="images/img.png" alt="">
                    <select id="item<?=$i?>">
                            <?for($q = 1; $q <= 9; $q++){?>
                           <option value="<?=$q?>"><?=$q?></option>
                           <?}?>
                        </select>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Добавить товар</a>
                    <div class="add"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?}?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.name a').click(function() {
                        $this = $(this);
                        var id = $this.parent().find('select').attr('id');
                        var count = $("#" + id).val();
                        alert(count);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'post.php',
                            data: {
                                itemid: id,
                                count: count
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $this.parent().find('.add').html('Товар добавлен!');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что означает эта запись? $("#" + id).val();    то есть что значит решетка? к решетке добавляем ID и значение value ?

Comment: # — значит ID (аналог document.getElementByID('id')). То есть получить элемент по его айди. #item = <div id="item">...</div>. $("#" + id).val() — получить значение (в твоём случае значение выбранного пункта).